$\lim_{x \to 0}\sin\frac{1}{x}$ doesn't exist using epsilon-delta
Any errors in my proof that I should correct upon?
For any $\epsilon>0$, $\exists\delta$: $|x-0|<\delta \implies \epsilon>\left|\sin\frac{1}{x}-L\right|$.
Now, for any such $\delta$ if it exists we can choose a $x=\frac{1}{n\pi}$. Then, $\left|\sin\frac{1}{x}-L\right|=|-L|=|L|$. Since $\epsilon$ can be chosen such that is is less than the limit, no limit can exist.

Note that $$\frac1{\sin\frac1{n\pi}}\ne \sin(n\pi)$$

Consider $x_n = \arcsin(1/n)$ or similar. Then $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ but $\csc x_n \to \infty$. You can turn this into an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ argument. If "exists" for you includes $\infty$, consider also $y_n = \arcsin(-1/n)$

@GeorgeCoote Your method implicitly assumes $sin(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Since OP wants to prove the limit's existence from first principles, such a shortcut is improper.

I wrote the wrong function in question, it is sin1/x actually

this is definitely too complex of an approach for the OP's needs but off the top of my head the most "elementary" version of @GeorgeCoote's approach is to find two sequences $x_n, x'_n$ that both tend to 0 ex: $\frac{1}{n}$ and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ and then show that the differences between $\frac{1}{x_n} \mod 2\pi$ and $\frac{1}{x'_n} \mod 2\pi$ never converge to 0. thus directly proving the limit does not exist.

A little more explanation. The value of proving those don't converge is that for each choice of $\frac{1}{x_n}$ there is a corresponding right triangle with unit diagonal whose height is $\sin(\frac{1}{x_n})$ thus if the two sequences never converge to each other then the corresponding triangles never converge, and so without knowing that $\sin(0) = 0$ we conclude that $\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ does not have a limit. We have two difference sequences of triangles both representing $\frac{1}{x_n}$ as $x_n \rightarrow 0$ and their corresponding $\sin(\frac{1}{x_n})$ are wildly different

So far you have shown that if a limit exists, we must have $L=0$ (it is smaller than any $\epsilon$). Now apply the same computation with $x = \frac{2}{(4n+1)\pi}$ to find that we must have $L=1$, a contradiction.
Also I would specify the following things:

Ensure it is clear that the $|\cdot|<\epsilon$ inequality is true for all $|x|<\delta$ when restating the definition of a limit.
Justify why you can find such an $n$ that $0<\frac{1}{n\pi}<\delta$.


Justification for 2: Using archimedean property, since $\pi$>0,  we can choose a positive integer n such that $n\pi>\frac{1}{\delta}$ $\implies$ $\frac{1}{n\pi}<\delta$

When you're trying to prove that a limit doesn't exist, it's not good to prove that you have infinitely many points where the function's value is $0$.
(Any other single value instead of $0$ is just as useless.)
What you can do instead is to make use of an infinite number of points where the function's value is $A$ and an infinite number of points where the function's value is $B$, where $B \neq A$.
The thing about $\sin\frac1x$ as $x$ approaches $0$ is that it hits all values in the interval $[-1,1]$ again and again. So you need to choose two values from that interval, say $1$ and $-1$ (or $0$ and $1$, as suggested in another answer)
and show that you always have both of those.
You can skip the "$\epsilon$ can be as small as we like" part. That's a true argument, but more sophisticated than you need. You can just pick a suitable value of $\epsilon$
such that the distance between $A$ and $B$ is more than $2\epsilon$, you're done.
For $-1$ and $1$, $\epsilon = \frac12$ is fine.
